# Python NonExistentTimeError

Tags: python, django, python-datetime

I'm creating a simple Django API where access tokens are used. The idea is that, when a user requests a token, said token is valid for the next 7 hours.

However when generating the token I obtain a Python NonExistentTimeError. Code is:

```
 #Django view
 ...
 expires = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=7)

 token = APIMasterToken.objects.create(
     token=token,
     expiration_date=expires
 )
```

However I obtain an exception generating a token with said date:

```
NonExistentTimeError at /api/obtain_master_token/
2013-03-10 02:05:12.179508
```

What does this error mean and how can I solve it?

EDIT: I just read the documentation and it would appear this error is raised when a day occurs that has a clock change following DST. However, I don't know how to solve the problem. Shouldn't the timedelta function take care of this?

Comment: What's the code that's actually throwing the `NonExistentTimeError`?

Comment: The line where the object is saved: `token = API...`

Comment: "Shouldn't the timedelta function take care of this?" - there are country-specific differences in DST, and Python datetimes are by default timezone-naive so there's really nothing for them to go on here. Try if it works sanely with a timezone-aware `datetime`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Django expects to work with [timezone aware datetime objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects).

From the Django documentation, the `now()` call would become:

```
import datetime
from django.utils.timezone import utc

now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
expires = now + datetime.timedelta(hours=7)
```

Better still, use the `now()` function from `django.utils.timezone`.

Both `datetime.now()` and `datetime.utcnow()` return naive `datetime` objects which is not what Django requires.  With a time zone applied to `expires`, Django is then able to convert back to UTC for storage as UTC in the database backend.

The `NonExistentTimeError` is actually thrown by code from the `pytz` module.  The [pytz documentation](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) is definitely worth reading as there's many gotchas when dealing with time zones.